# Remove observations in dataframe based on value of another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 555L, 555L, 555L), City = c("NEW YORK", 
"NEW YORK", "NEW YORK", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I want to remove the rows if the `ID` has a frequency greater than 1 in another dataframe, similar to this:

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(ID = c(123L, 555L), Freq = 2:1), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Because `ID`=123 has a frequency of 2, I want to remove them from the original dataframe (`df`). We can keep `ID`=555 in the original dataframe, because in the second dataframe they have a frequency of 1.

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% anti_join(df2 %>% filter(Freq >= 2))` or `df2 %>% filter(Freq < 2) %>% left_join(df, multiple = "all")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `dplyr` you can do some filtering like this

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%
  filter(ID %in% (df2%>%filter(Freq>1)%>%pull(ID)))

#>    ID     City
#> 1 123 NEW YORK
#> 2 123 NEW YORK
#> 3 123 NEW YORK

Created on 2023-03-29 with reprex v2.0.2
```